# Upload app on client app store connect with .p12 and .mobileprovision

Tags: ios, xcode, p12, mobileprovision

My question may be silly...

I have to upload an application, via xcode, on the app store connect of a client.

I only have the .p12 file and .mobileprovision file of the client.

What is the protocole ?

Because after I have "installed" the mobileprovision file and the p12, after the archive creation, I have this error when I want to distribute the app:
"No accounts with App Store Connect access have been found for the team "XXXX". App Store Connect access is required for App Store distribution"

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You need to add your client's apple developer account in your xcode

Comment: You can request your client for an app specific password

Answer (score 0):

1) Apple introduce the Two way factor authentication. So first you need to login the account by Xcode -> Preference-> Accounts.
2) After login it might ask the two way authentication.
 3) Your need to choose any one of the trusted device.
 4) After that you will receive the code send by apple use that code and logged in.
6) Then You can uncheck and check the automatically manage signing.
 7) It will help you to create the certificates again.
 8) Then you should archive your app and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In General > Signing automatically is uncheck.

In Signing (Release), Provisioning Profile is OK, Team is OK and Signing Certificate is OK (it's the provisioning profile of the client, the team of the client and the certificate of the client. is it ok?).

The archive creation is OK.

But the distribution (with the option iOS App Store) failed with the error;
"No accounts with App Store Connect access have been found for the team "XXXX". App Store Connect access is required for App Store distribution"

I don't know if I have to link the customer's team to my account?